# Identicon problem

Tags: support, identicon

Is it possible to get back my real identicon?

My real one has been exchanged because I posted a message with a double account (I deleted it) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43427/playing-around-with-spherical-k-ellispe-on-the-sphere-surface).

I know this is not important, but identicons exist for a purpose, and this is wrong.

Comment: Do you want both accounts to be merged?

Answer (score 2):

You could open the full size image on your old profile, save the image to your local drive and then upload it as an image under your profile. I just tried it and it worked OK. That's assuming you meant you just deleted the question and not the entire account, but I can see you still have two accounts there so that doesn't seem to be the case.